# can't sign in to newly created account

Tags: login, sudo, password

I have created a new account to change my username. I have used the following to create the account `sudo useradd -c "other" other` and then `sudo passwd other` then I put my new account in the sudoers using `visudo` to be able to use the sudo command.

When I logged out of my main account to log in to the other account, after I put my password it reloads the login page to select an account.

I am able to login with the terminal but get the GUI

Answer (score 0):

What i have realized is that when i created the account, its home directory was owned by group and user root. What i did is sudo chgrp “name of the account” /home/“name of the account” and the same thing with chown